# Inbox notification counter doesn't go away anymore after clicking outside the window

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox

I noticed(since last few hours) that whenever I get a notification now and when I click on the notification icon, the notification window opens as usual. But the unusual thing is that even when I click outside this notification window(as shown in the gif below), that notification reminder is still there. Before today, whenever I used to click outside that notification window, that reminder/counter used to go away but not anymore.

Is this a bug or an intentional change.

[image]

Comment: I experienced this as well on MSE earlier. (I don't think I've had any inbox notifications since then, though.)

Comment: Cross-posted to MSE: [Notification counter doesn't go away anymore after clicking outside the window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383270/241919)

Comment: @AndrewT.: Thanks, I've added the [status-review] tag to the MSE post so that it creates a ticket for us internally.

Comment: I have this too. The notification won't go away until I click the offered link, which page might already be open anyway. And if I try to close the dialog by clicking again on the notification icon (as before), it opens my profile page! That's the job of the icon to its left. They have broken something that did **not need fixing**.

Comment: ... and also, even though I clicked through to a recent notification, it has reappeared some minutes later (the triggering pinged comment has not been edited).

Comment: Going further back... I'm getting pinged when I wasn't specifically pinged. I have enough brain to revisit a question I am interested in. Perhaps the next comment addressed mine, or it didn't. Please cremate the AI robot.

Comment: This appears to be fixed; not seeing this behavior anymore.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes, this seems to be fixed(for me too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be fixed. [See marrados' answer to the corresponding MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383327/335251):

> We just pushed the fix for the issue. During the implementation of the new inbox features we had to touch existing code, too, and unfortunately we caused this bug.
>
> Thank you very much for the report and even more for your patience. We're sorry you've experienced those issues and hope that the planned improvements will make up for it!

Comment: This (or a similar problem) is not fixed or has reappeared or is somewhat similar, at least [as of today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421769/unread-inbox-messages-indicator-does-not-go-away), but my post has been closed as a dupe...

Comment: @false: Is it actually not going away after clicking on the notifications or marking the individual notifications as read? Because it is intentional that it doesn't dismiss the notification unless you take action on the notification itself. See this MSE post about the inbox improvements going live for everyone: [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251)

Comment: If it's *not* working as intended, you should post it as an answer to that MSE announcement here, if someone hasn't reported the bug there already.

Comment: Effectively, the new inbox makes the previously "broken" functionality intended, right?

Comment: @KevinB: Basically, yes. The changes weren't supposed to affect those outside the testing group originally, so it was a bug when this was originally reported here – but now the changes have been officially released for everyone. That said, there's an entry in the FAQ in that MSE announcement about the possibility of adding an option to keep the original functionality (of auto-marking everything as read upon opening the inbox), and you can upvote the corresponding request in the answers there if you would like us to implement an option for that.