# Was there a UI change that prevents the inbox count from resetting when the mailbox is clicked without selecting a message?

Tags: support, user-interface, global-inbox

This question is similar to [Inbox notification counter doesn't go away anymore after clicking outside the window](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421137/inbox-notification-counter-doesnt-go-away-anymore-after-clicking-outside-the-wi), but I didn't see the issue appear until today.

Between yesterday and today (maybe the day before yesterday), there looks to be a change in how the mailbox message count is reset that affects Firefox. Often I receive replies when on the same page. In that case I would just click the inbox icon up to reset the message count to zero. That stopped working today.

Now clicking the inbox opens the message list, but it does not reset the new message count zero.

I'm using Firefox 102.5 [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Experimental_builds_and_ESR). Was this intentional, or an unforeseen side effect of some change? Is there anything I can do to restore the old behavior? It seem like unnecessary traffic to require a full page-reload when I'm already looking at the page.

Comment: Can't you just click the `Mark all read` link?

Comment: Also I'm not entirely sure if you know of the [Inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/393786) that went live today, or if you've actually missed them and thus are a bit confused why it behaves differently now.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384149/200898

Comment: No, I had no clue a new inbox was going live today. My eyes are no longer as crisp as they were, so little text in the top right corner does not stick out (in dark-mode) - but I've now found the "Mark all read" -- and it works. I answer programming questions on SO, not sure where I would have seen notice about a new inbox. You can close this. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It would be in the yellow menu on the right side, under **Featured**

Comment: Right you are -- that "Featured" area has basically been almost static for the past three months or so. I had even thought of asking a question here about whether it was still active -- but knew the automatic downvote squad would pounce so that question went unasked. Glad to see it active again. (I actually enjoyed reading the featured issues -- but had gotten out of the habit for this exact reason)

Comment: That's odd you say that... as the person who manages what goes into the featured box, we've had at least 5-10 different items in there that were featured network-wide alone, excluding the work the mods here on SO are doing to do tag cleanups. If you're truly not seeing that there's different stuff there almost weekly, I'd be concerned that there's a bug or something isn't allowing them to update properly for you.

Comment: I would look at it just about every day, and to be honest wouldn't focus on how it was different), but for quite some time, there wasn't much featured there. Both there and "Hot Meta Posts" were regular stops, but neither had been that active. Where before (I don't know how long ago), they would change almost daily, giving me reason to hop over a catch up with whatever was going on. I'm not saying it was a bad thing, just that nothing had been active to cause me to hop over and check it out. It's notable, because that was something I missed doing.

Comment: They don't change daily. The hot meta posts might if Meta is really active but the featured generally stick around for a week or two each at minimum. For important things, we do keep them up for up to a month but the system automatically removes them after about a month.

Comment: Yay, now I need to do two clicks :/ That's... progress?

Comment: Also the red number on top of the inbox does not correspond with the number of unread messages. Though I think that's an old bug which never got fixed.

Comment: I don't like this.