# How can I mark a single inbox notification as read?

Tags: support, global-inbox

My inbox shows a red icon and indicates many unread comments. If I click and read one such a comment, nothing happens.

How do I mark a single inbox notification as read?

It is disturbing to see the same old comments as unread all the time.

I don't want to mark all the comments as read. I want just a single comment be marked as read when I read it.

A moderator suggested that the question: "[Was there a UI change that prevents the inbox count from resetting when the mailbox is clicked without selecting a message?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421735/was-there-a-ui-change-that-prevents-the-inbox-count-from-resetting-when-the-mail)" was the same as mine. This is not the case, the behavior I observed was that there was no way to change the count of unread messages. **This** **problem is now solved** and does not deserve more time and measures.

Comment: [There is a button to mark everything as read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROCLTl.png)

Comment: @The Thonnu: Now I know that I can **mark all comments as read**. But this is not what I want. Comments should be **selectively** marked as read when I read them. This answer is not there.

Comment: That dupe target does *not* have an answer explaining how to mark individual notifications as read. It just has a couple of comments that link to a relevant MSE page, but you then have to click on another MSE link to get to the actual info about toggling read / unread status. That's rather obscure, IMHO...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To toggle the read / unread state of a single comment you need to click the little envelope icon, located on the upper right side of the comment. That can be a little tricky on touch screens: if you don't aim accurately it just takes you to the place where the comment is posted.

From [Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread, and a filtered inbox view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/334566) on MSE:

> Left click on the closed-envelope icon ( [image: 1] ) on the right side of the notification to mark it as read without opening it.

> #### Marking notifications as unread
>
> Read notifications can be marked as unread by clicking on the open-envelope icon ( [image: 2] ) on the right side of the notification.

Comment: Thank you. I swear it didn't work that way when I tried before. I could open and close envelopes, and nothing happened with my inbox; it steadily showed many unread messages. But I also rebooted the PC.