# Unread inbox messages indicator does not go away

Tags: bug, user-interface

For the past day or two, the red unread inbox message indicator has not gone away after reading the messages; the only way to remove it is to "Mark all read". This is pretty irritating, because I have to remember which messages I already read.

This is not a duplicate of the other post a month ago. At that time, everything worked fine until very recently.

Comment: That bug was turned into a feature

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148 & https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382695

Comment: Btw, if you actually open the notifications by clicking on them, they will be marked as  read, and when you have no unread left, the indicator will go away.

Comment: If you notice there is a small mail icon at the top right in each notification, you can mark an individual notification as read / unread by clicking those.

Comment: There should be special versions of upvote on meta "I also do not read the announcement" and "I also do not check if similar issues reported over last couple days" :)

Comment: @FZs: Not true. It only goes away if I "Mark all read"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: And also about "last couple of months"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: Thank you, this is indeed a good suggestion I did not notice beforehand!

Comment: @false the notification is marked as read if you open it in the same tab, opening in a new tab doesn't seem to mark it as read, maybe that can be a feature request.

Comment: @false Well, then I can't reproduce your issue. Left-clicking or even middle-clicking on any unread notification does mark it as read for me (as does 'Mark all read' and the mail icon).